# Decision tree with different split criterion than information gain

Tags: python, machine-learning

I'd like to create a decision tree in python with a different split criterion than information gain, something like "1-information gain" (something like the opposite of impurity measure, like as similarity measure). 
Does already exist something like this? paper included.
Thanks

Comment: You said "paper included", but I don't see a link or description of the optimization you're suggesting (that is, using similarity measurement). That said, if your measurement equates to a *distance* conceptually (for example, if the similarity measurement goes toward infinity the more instances match), this is reducible to *information gain* -- the measure of entropy *is* another form of similarity.

Comment: This is off-topic for Stack Overflow, and certainly too broad/vague.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it exists. There are many research papers:

https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/5e44/d49b2268421d7ddf09d68be9aa689359b772.pdf

https://www.springerprofessional.de/en/splitting-method-for-decision-tree-based-on-similarity-with-mixe/16031946